# Testing ember.js application with cucumber and capybara-webkit fails to run ember code

Tags: ember.js, cucumber, capybara-webkit

Trying to test an Ember application with Cucumber and Capybara-webkit to run the javascript.  The Ember code runs in a regular browser, and produces a welcome message.

I've created a Cucumber feature which looks for the welcome message generated by the Ember code, and it doesn't show up.  I've dumped the 'page.body' to see what's there, and there's nothing.

I've added a

```
jQuery ->
  $("body").append("Foo!")
```

and it shows up, so I know that the javascript is being run.

Thanks!

Comment: what does your ember app look like? are you doing a simple "App = Ember.Application.create()" or something more complex w/ require or minispade? are you running initialize yourself at the bottom of your javascript file? is this ember 1.0 RC1 or an older version? what version of jQuery and handlebars are you using?

Comment: It's a simple "App = Ember.Application.create()" (well, I do set "LOG_TRANSITIONS: true", but taking that out has no effect).  I'm using 1.0 RC1, jQuery 1.9.1, and Handlebars 1.0.0-rc.3.